# How to avoid borderless window losing focus?

Tags: overwatch

Whenever I move my mouse from left to the right quickly, the cursor walks out of the window onto my right screen. If I make a click in the moment before the application forces the cursor back to the window's center again, the application's window obviously loses focus.

I don't actually want to adjust the ingame sensitivity or my dpi to get around this, nor do I want to play in fullscreen mode (since I know my configurations and hardware are also used by the pros, and I don't think they have this problem either).

So what else can I do to avoid this happening?

Comment: To each their own I guess, but why exactly do you not want to use fullscreen?

Comment: Not the OP but I don't like to use fullscreen because games sometimes glitch out or crash when alt-tabbing out of fullscreen instead of borderless window. Or because you still want to see the game while you're in another window (such as flipping back and forth between chat, or OBS) while playing

Comment: Does this only happen when you're in menus or waiting for the match to start, or does it even happen while you're actively controlling your character? For me, I can't actually leave the window in Overwatch while controlling the character without hitting alt-tab first, but when I'm in menus or something, then the mouse can go left/right to another window. Basically, it doesn't seem to leave the window for me unless the game is showing me an actual mouse cursor.

Comment: @Sterno: Actually it also happens when beeing in match. Thats where it is causing the trouble. Note: the actuall problem seems to be (since it happens when I very quickly move my mouse a  full mousepad distance) that it is caused that I some how manage to move the cursor out of the window before the application just pulls it back into the windows center as it is usually done by a app to exactly prevent this from happening. But here somehow I can make it to not force pull the cursor back fast enough so it actually can move out of the window. (in rare cases)

Comment: Do you have a high DPI mouse? I'm just taking a shot in the dark here, but if your mouse has a high DPI, it will move much faster, and perhaps you are moving the mouse so fast that the game doesn't even recognize the mouse isn't there anymore.

Comment: @MageXy: Well actually thats what I meant by pros. My dpi is 1600. thats not so far out of that it should cause this to happen on general basis I think.

Comment: @Sterno Instead of Alt+Tab use Alt+Enter to exit full screen when you need to Alt+Tab. I'm using it CONSTANTLY and am yet to get a single crash.

Comment: @ИвоНедев: This actually is one fo the reasons I don't like to use fullscreen. Does this exist as OP on this site? If not so I would like to write a post asking about it so you can put it in there as an answer. Since if this really works, it is too usefull as an idea, to just be lost in a comment.

Comment: @Zaibis I haven't seen it around tbh.

Comment: @ИвоНедев: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/298213/88641 If you wouldn't mind to put it in as an answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me too when the windows mouse sensitivity was set to 100%, the problem was solved by lowering it to 50%.

Go to Mouse & touchpad settings select Additional mouse options then select Pointer Options and under Motion you slide it down to half or even lower.

Comment: Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of having a high DPI mouse?

Comment: This makes no sense to me,why this works ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев: I actually can't tell how Sputnik got on that, but actually it feels to me like Overwatch isn't capturing the cursor movement in it self. Since while changing the cursor speed actually changed the sensitivity in the menus, it hadn't any impact on the ingame aim sensitivity. So probably Overwatch captures the mouse movement in a way that isn't relying on the OS cursor. To be honest I have no idea. But just try it out, and you will see what I'm refering to. And if you then come up with an idea yourself I'd be happy to hear from you.

Comment: @Zaibis I'm guessing then that due to the reduced speed the mouse doesn't go beyond the borders of the window behind it. As you only go so much in any direction before going back and essentially hovering around the middle of the screen. I might test it when I get home, but going too far in a single direction will show quick enough.

Comment: @ИвоНедев: Yeah, that is exactly what happens. But I would have assumed that overwatch would rely on the delta x and delta y of the cursors movement anyway to determine the crosshair movement, and I was suprised that it appearingly doesn't. So I thought this was the point you had been confused about aswell.

Comment: @Zaibis They probably will at one point. Early after release the game would focus on TeamViewer when a user comes online or wahtever, seams they've fixed that now, so it's a constant improvement even behind the scenes.