# Are there any workarounds, to avoid fullscreened applications to crash when alt+tabing?

Tags: windows

Simply said.

Are there any workarounds that prevent fullscreened applications from crashing at times?

Additional it would be great if this workaround also avoids all the other negative sideeffects like rarely changing windows display resolution, having display bugs when focusing the application again, or messing up the volume configurations.

Comment: I'm guessing you're looking for a workaround *aside from borderless windowed fullscreen*?

Comment: @Nolonar: yeah, since a borderlesswindowed application isn't a fullscreened one in that moment anymore. Otherwise jsut not starting the application would be a workaround aswell. (No ofense intended :) )

Comment: I think this question is too generic. Different applications crash for different reasons, so how do you except a single method to solve this problem for all applications.

Comment: a borderless window *is* for all intents and purposes, fullscreen. just use that.

Comment: @Rapitor - fullscreen has better performance than borderless window since you don't have to draw all the other windows UI, and if you aren't running the game at your main resolution to get better performance, full screen also stretches it to fill. They aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most, not all, but most apps and games support Alt+Enter.

Alt+Enter is a shortcut that toggles between full-screen and windowed mode. It generally doesn't mess with resolution and such. And is a great alternative to Alt+Tab as the later can sometimes take ages to execute (besides crashing as OP mentions) as the machine needs to load desktop and then when you go back in the game it needs to reaload everything in there.

Throughout my experience I've found Alt+Enter to a much better option to Alt+Tabbing, takes much less time and am yet to experience a crash.

Another positive is that you can actually keep your game/app somewhere on the screen while doing whatever it is that you switched for.

Comment: Not most games support windowed/fullscreen with Alt + Enter based on my experience, only "some".

Comment: @user598527 If the game can has a windowed option it supports it.

Comment: But he already sayed to @Nolonar that he wanted to play it full screen and not in borderless windowed fullscreen. So as what you say implies that he's gonna need to play in windowed mode, it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: @ИвоНедев: It does not, Valve games for example.